# jsf check user logged in

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3

How can I check if a user is logged in using jsf?

This is how I am doing it and it's not working:

```xml
<ui:fragment rendered="#{!request.getUserPrincipal().getName().equalsIgnoreCase('anonymous')}">
    <h:outputLink value="logout">
        <h:outputText value="Logout" />
    </h:outputLink>
</ui:fragment>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just check if [`HttpServletRequest#getUserPrincipal()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal%28%29) is not `null`.

```html
<ui:fragment rendered="#{request.userPrincipal != null}">
    <h:outputLink value="logout">
        <h:outputText value="Logout" />
    </h:outputLink>
</ui:fragment>
```

It also works for [`HttpServletRequest#getRemoteUser()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser%28%29).

```html
<ui:fragment rendered="#{request.remoteUser != null}">
    <h:outputLink value="logout">
        <h:outputText value="Logout" />
    </h:outputLink>
</ui:fragment>
```

Comment: Ty but but how do you compare with string?

Comment: Just do `#{request.remoteUser == 'some user name'}`.