# JSF verify user state

Tags: java, jsf

After the user is successfully logged in i would normally put some of his info on a session object. Then I would use a Filter applied to all pages to check if any user is logged in or not.

How can I achieve something like this with JSF 2.0?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jsf check user logged in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704027/jsf-check-user-logged-in)

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL this doesn't duplicate it exactly

Comment: but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662367/writing-an-authorization-filter-for-my-web-appjsf-2-0) is

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF HTTP Session Login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841361/jsf-http-session-login)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put all of login required pages to subfolders and leave login.xhtml at root directory.

you may keep your user in session scope with a class called identity you can 
then add these declarations to your pages.xml.

so you will not need to check everywhere if user logged in.

```
<page view-id="*">
    <navigation>
        <rule if-outcome="home">
            <redirect view-id="/base/home.xhtml"/>
        </rule>
    </navigation>

    <navigation from-action="#{identity.logout}">            
        <rule if="#{not identity.loggedIn}">
            <redirect view-id="/login.xhtml"/>
        </rule>            
    </navigation>
</page> 

<page view-id="/modul*" login-required="true"></page>
<page view-id="/popup*" login-required="true"></page>
```